# mcanvas vs svg vs html5 canvas

Tags: android, canvas, svg, raphael

I have tested recently in the mobile browser which has *Raphael* canvas where we can draw lines etc using tablet.

The speed and precision lacks when using svg to draw on browser for example, the lines breaks in between when drawing even though the touch is not stopped during the move etc.

So I m researching on what is used in the drawing app which are working perfectly for touch screens.

And if we want to have an drawing app on mobile browser which is best canvas or svg or neither as we don't want breaking lines when drawing?

And where I can start research more on drawing api's that used by android for drawing that is used by"pen memo, S2 and other touching apps".

Updated: check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackit/h4Wrr/)

```
var canvas = $("#canvas");
paper = Raphael("canvas");
var clicking = false;
var line;
var pathArray = [];

 canvas.bind("mousedown", _mousedownHandler);
 canvas.bind("touchstart", _mousedownHandler);
function _mousedownHandler(event){
     clicking = true;
 // _drawArrowLineBegin(e);
        if(event.type == "touchstart"){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] || event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
        }
    _drawFreeLineBegin(event);
};

function _mousemoveHandler(event){
 // _drawArrowLineMove(event);
        if(event.type == "touchmove"){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] || event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
        }
    _drawFreeLineMove(event);
};
function _mouseupHandler(event){
    clicking = false;
};
function _enableEvents(){
           canvas.bind("mousemove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        canvas.one("mouseup.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
        canvas.bind("touchmove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        canvas.one("touchend.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
};
function _drawArrowLineBegin(e) {
    clicking = true;
        line = paper.path("M" + (e.offsetX || e.clientX) + " " + (e.offsetY || e.clientY) + "L" + (e.offsetX || e.clientX) + " " + (e.offsetY || e.clientY)).attr({stroke:'#FF0000', 'stroke-width': 2, 'arrow-end': 'classic-wide-long'});
    pathArray = line.attr("path");
 _enableEvents();
    }
function _drawArrowLineMove(e){
        if(clicking == false) return;
    if (pathArray[1][1] != undefined) { // not IE 8
        pathArray[1][1] = e.offsetX || e.clientX;
        pathArray[1][2] = e.offsetY || e.clientY;
    } else {
        pathArray = pathArray.replace(/L\d+ \d+$/, "L" + e.offsetX + " " + e.offsetY);
    }

    line.attr({path: pathArray});
}
function _drawFreeLineBegin(e) {
    clicking = true;
       line =  paper.path("M"
                + (e.pageX) + ","
                + (e.pageY)).attr({stroke:'#FF0000', 'stroke-width': 2});
     pathArray = line.attr("path");
_enableEvents();
    }
function _drawFreeLineMove(e){
        if(clicking == false) return;
    line.attr("path",line.attr("path")
                        + "L"
                                    + (e.pageX)
                                    + ","
                                    + (event.pageY));
}
```

Comment: It seems to me more like an implementation issue. Both are suitable for what you've mentioned. Any way you could create a fiddle for your section of the app that draws line?

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya just updated with jsfiddle

Comment: The implementation needs a bit doing up. I will put some time into it and create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue mentioned regarding speed and performance is more intrinsic to the JavaScript library being used in SVG. In your fiddle, the performance issue in drawing is primarily because of the ever-expanding array of path and the fact that the entire path array is re-processed on every touch move. There is no simple way to fix this than working around it.

> I have recreated your implementation with pure Raphael (and no jQuery.) 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/kUQ7E/

The implementation has two aspects:

1. It bypasses Raphael's heavy `attr` function and directly sets the element's path using `doodle.node.setAttribute('d', pathstring);`
2. It uses a timeout to ignore touch up and down within a tolerable interval.

**The fiddle (as of revision 24) looks like:**

```
Raphael("canvas", function () {
    var win = Raphael._g.win,
        doc = win.document,
        hasTouch = "createTouch" in doc,

        M = "M",
        L = "L",
        d = "d",
        COMMA = ",",
        // constant for waiting doodle stop
        INTERRUPT_TIMEOUT_MS = hasTouch ? 100 : 1,
        // offset for better visual accuracy
        CURSOR_OFFSET = hasTouch ? 0 : -10,

        paper = this,
        path = "", // hold doodle path commands
        // this element draws the doodle
        doodle = paper.path(path).attr({
            "stroke": "rgb(255,0,0)"
        }),

        // this is to capture mouse movements
        tracker = paper.rect(0, 0, paper.width, paper.height).attr({
            "fill": "rgb(255,255,255)",
            "fill-opacity": "0.01"
        }),
        active = false, // flag to check active doodling
        repath = false, // flag to check if a new segment starts
        interrupt; // this is to connect jittery touch

    tracker.mousedown(function () {
        interrupt && (interrupt = clearTimeout(interrupt));
        active = true;
        repath = true;
    });

    tracker.mousemove(function (e, x, y) {
        // do nothing if doodling is inactive
        if (!active) {
            return;
        }

        // Fix for Raphael's touch xy bug
        if (hasTouch && 
                (e.originalEvent.targetTouches.length === 1)) {
            x = e.clientX + 
                (doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop || 0);
            y = e.clientY + 
                (doc.documentElement.scrollLeft || doc.body.scrollLeft || 0);
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        // Insert move command for a new segment
        if (repath) {
            path += M + (x + CURSOR_OFFSET) + COMMA + 
                    (y + CURSOR_OFFSET);
            repath = false;
        }
        path += L + (x + CURSOR_OFFSET) + COMMA + 
                (y + CURSOR_OFFSET); // append line point

        // directly access SVG element and set path
        doodle.node.setAttribute(d, path);
    });

    // track window mouse up to ensure mouse up even outside
    // paper works.
    Raphael.mouseup(function () {
        interrupt && (interrupt = clearTimeout(interrupt));
        // wait sometime before deactivating doodle
        interrupt = setTimeout(function () {
            active = false;
        }, INTERRUPT_TIMEOUT_MS);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working better. Can you explain fix for Raphael touch which you commented?

Comment: Also can you tell me why you are not using jquery for mouse/touch events?

Comment: (1) The Raphael Touch fix prevents from getting NaN,NaN for touch x,y on certain touch devices (including iOS 6). (2) Just sticking to one library + Raphael's event handlers are lighter (+ more native)!

Comment: I am trying your sample without using the rectangle's events, using Rahphael mouseevents, which is working fine when using mouse but not touch pads. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/stackit/aUPwG/1/

Comment: Why doing this way? The entire Windows' mouse down will be fired by this.

Comment: How about now ? http://jsfiddle.net/veeramarni/kUQ7E/47/ I am just trying to avoid the rectangle otherwise I need to change a lot in my real code. Can you help me making this work with touch?

Comment: Your code does not account for the fact that touchstart event is not transferred to mousedown when run on iFrame (bug.) I have updated my fiddle to loose the tracker rect. http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/kUQ7E/49/

Comment: I have seen http://www.matkakuume.net/freehand.html using canvas which is very fast than your code. Can we make Raphael that faster?

Comment: I doubt. Canvas is Raster in nature and as such the load on browser is not related to complexity of graphics. For vector graphics such as SVG, this isn't the case.

Comment: Ok, how do you smooth lines instead? I am look at http://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html . Can this be done using Raphael?

Comment: Though I can answer here itself. I would suggest you create a separate SO question for the benefit of community.

Comment: Did you get a chance to see the SO Question?

Comment: Not yet. Celebration 15th August. :-)

Comment: Did you get a chance to comment on it?

Comment: I know it is been long time, but you had help me with the smothering the lines. Now i'm working on getting a eraser work on it. Do you have any tips for it?